# location: ^3.2.1, Unable to destroy activity

Tags: flutter

**Update 1**

Found the cause, the problem is with `location: ^3.2.1`, To recreate the issue, just create a flutter project from Android Studio, add this dependency in `pubspec.yaml` or in your config file. Just run the app, and press back button, check your `logcat`, You will get exception like,

```
E/AndroidRuntime(21857): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.guna.flutter_app_test/com.guna.flutter_app_test.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter activity
E/AndroidRuntime(21857):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5111)
E/AndroidRuntime(21857):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5140)
E/AndroidRuntime(21857):    at android.app.servertransaction.DestroyActivityItem.execute(DestroyActivityItem.java:44)
E/AndroidRuntime(21857):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
E/AndroidRuntime(21857):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
E/AndroidRuntime(21857):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
E/AndroidRuntime(21857):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(21857):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/AndroidRuntime(21857):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/AndroidRuntime(21857):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(21857):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/AndroidRuntime(21857):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
E/AndroidRuntime(21857): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter activity
E/AndroidRuntime(21857):    at com.lyokone.location.FlutterLocationService.setActivity(Unknown Source:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(21857):    at com.lyokone.location.LocationPlugin.deinitialize(LocationPlugin.java:121)
E/AndroidRuntime(21857):    at com.lyokone.location.LocationPlugin.detachActivity(LocationPlugin.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime(21857):    at com.lyokone.location.LocationPlugin.onDetachedFromActivity(LocationPlugin.java:69)
E/AndroidRuntime(21857):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.detachFromActivity(FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.java:346)
E/AndroidRuntime(21857):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onDetach(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:512)
E/AndroidRuntime(21857):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onDestroy(FlutterActivity.java:577)
E/AndroidRuntime(21857):    at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:8245)
E/AndroidRuntime(21857):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1344)
E/AndroidRuntime(21857):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5096)
```

**Old post**

I have two screens, named `Login` and `Dashboard`.

I want to close the app without go to `Login` while press back on `Dashboard` screen.

Also while open the app next time app should go to dashboard, without login, I managed this login status using Shared Preference.

But I have used `WillPopScope` in my `Dashboard`, in that I used `SystemNavigator.pop()` to skip login and close the app. This leads to crash with exception `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.guna.jnstores/com.guna.jnstores.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter activity`.

I have tried with `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil`, this doesn't remove `Login` from stack, I also tried with `pushReplacementNamed`, `pushAndRemoveUntil` these removes `Login` from stack, But I'm getting the same exception.

Comment: when you push dashboard from login screen, push it using `Navigator.pushReplacement`, which will remove the current screen from stack/list and adds the dashboard as the current screen, if this doesnt work, you need to show us how you are handling the route and with which navigator

Comment: @Yadu, I have updated my post.

Comment: @Gunaseelan were you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you are developing a Flutter app, and not a native one in which Flutter is only a module. This would pretty much explain the native error you're getting: since Flutter apps only have one activity -- the `MainActivity` -- the "previous" activity must be null. Let me know if I'm wrong, though.

You shouldn't use `SystemNavigator.pop()` in an exclusively Flutter app; that method is to be used in Flutter instances that "reside" inside native (ie. non-Flutter) apps.

Instead, while navigating to Dashboard from Login, use the [pushAndRemoveUntil](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushAndRemoveUntil.html) method (or [its "named" counterpart](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushNamedAndRemoveUntil.html)); that way, you don't need `WillPopScope` - pressing the hardware back button will close the app.

Comment: Well, `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` does remove all previous routes if `routePredicate` is something like this: `(Route<dynamic> route) => false)`. Anyway, in your use case, `pushReplacementNamed` is okay, too. What do you mean you are getting the same exception? You shouldn't call `SystemNavigator.pop()` at all. Simply remove your `WillPopScope`, and if Login has been removed from the stack, pressing the back button while on Dashboard will exit the app as intended.

Comment: Added +1 because it fulfill the requirement of older post.